# Consolidate C# Code for Event throwing from Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a threaded networking class from where I need to throw events under different circumstances. The code for throwing the events asynchronously looks like this:

```
    void FireCreateRoomRequestReceived(CreateRoomRequestArguments arguments)
    {
        if (CryptSetupReceived == null)
            return;

        _AysncManager.Post(new SendOrPostCallback(delegate(object obj)
        {
            CreateRoomRequestReceived(this, arguments);
        }), null);
    }

    void FireInviteToRoomRequestReceived(InviteToRoomRequestArguments arguments)
    {
        if (InviteToRoomRequestReceived == null)
            return;

        _AysncManager.Post(new SendOrPostCallback(delegate(object obj)
        {
            InviteToRoomRequestReceived(this, arguments);
        }), null);
    }

    void FireMessageContentReceived(MessageContentArguments arguments)
    {
        if (MessageContentReceived == null)
            return;

        _AysncManager.Post(new SendOrPostCallback(delegate(object obj)
        {
            MessageContentReceived(this, arguments);
        }), null);
    }
```

My Question is, if I could consolidate code like this somehow. I have no Idea how I would do this.

Comment: You pattern is a `NullReferenceException` race-condition waiting to happen. You should take a copy of the event and check that for null. e.g. `EventHandler ev = SomeEvent; if (ev != null) ev(sender, args);` and do this *all* within the `SendOrPostCallback`

Comment: Ok allright. Thanks for that hint!

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you can address your "consolidation" question, along with the thread-safety issue, by implementing a simple extension method to handle your events. This is actually a fairly common technique:

```
static class Extensions
{
    public static void Raise<T>(this EventHandler<T> handler, object sender, T args)
    {
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(sender, args);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that to do this, you will have to make sure your events are declared as `EventHandler<T>` types. E.g.:

```
public event EventHandler<CreateRoomRequestArguments> CryptSetupReceived;
public event EventHandler<InviteToRoomRequestArguments> InviteToRoomRequestReceived;
public event EventHandler<MessageContentArguments> MessageContentReceived;
```

The above extension method simply raises the event. In your case, where you want to use (apparently…you left out the declaration, so we have to rely on inference) a `SynchronizationContext` object to asynchronously invoke the handler, you can do it like this:

```
public static void RaiseAsync<T>(this EventHandler<T> handler,
    object sender, T args, SynchronizationContext context)
{
    if (handler != null)
    {
        context.Post(o => handler(sender, args), null);
    }
}
```

To actually use these methods, just call them on the event of interest. E.g.:

```
MessageContentArguments messageContentArguments = ...; // init as appropriate

MessageContentReceived.RaiseAsync(this, messageContentArguments, _AsyncManager);
```